# callback doesnot work in pool.map_async()

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

In the following simple program, the callback passed to pool.map_async() does not seem to work properly. Could someone point out what is wrong?

```
import os
import multiprocessing
import time

def cube(x):
    return "{}^3={}".format(x, x**3)
def prt(value):
    print(value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    result = pool.map_async(cube, range(1,1000), callback=prt)
    finish_time = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Program finished in {finish_time-start_time} seconds")


$ python3 /var/tmp/cube_map_async_callback.py
Program finished in 0.0001492840237915516 seconds
$
```

Comment: Add line `result.get()` right after you initialize the `result` variable. Without that line, you are not actually waiting for the tasks to be completed at all. You probably want to use `pool.map` here instead of it's async version.

Comment: Thanks. that works. Would you elaborate about your recommandation to use pool.map here  instead of it's async version?

Comment: using `pool.map(...)` is the same as doing `pool.map_async(...).get()`. In essence it blocks until the results are ready by inlining the call to `.get()`. Since you would be doing that anyway, I suggested using `pool.map` instead